# custom cache reload in java on weblogic

Tags: java, spring, caching, weblogic11g

I have a requirement to cache xml bean java objects by reading xml’s from database . I am using a HashMap in memory to maintain my java objects. I am using spring for DI and Weblogic 11g app server.

Can you please suggest me a mechanism to reload cache when there is an update in xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of weblogic p13n cache for this purpose, instead of using your own HashMap to cache the java objects. You will have to configure p13n-cache-config.xml file, which contains, TTL, max value etc. for your cache.

Coming to the first point, the cache will be automatically reloaded after the TTL time is done with. For manually clearing cache, You can implement a Servlet kind of thing, which you can hit directly from your browser (can restrict it for a particular URL). In that servlet clear the cache which you want to reload.

weblogic p13n cache provides you method for cluster aware cache clear as well, in case you need it, in case you want to use your own HashMap for caching, provide a update method for that HashMap and clear the java objects that you want to be reloaded and then call the cache creation method.